# Function "Extract by Mask" in batch mode - just one resulting layer

Tags: batch, extract-by-mask

I would like to clip 25 raster layers with self-made polygon using "Extract by Mask" function. The problem is that I am still receiving just one processed layer, instead of 25 processed layers. Despite the fact, that I am working in Batch mode and I always upload all layers, which I want to clip.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?  Please [edit] your question to let us know.